# Check predicate

Tags: prolog

I've a problem.
I have 5 constants.

```
C(1).
C(2).
C(3).
C(4).
C(5).
```

And I've a predicate named "check" that receives two arguments.

Example:

```
check( [C(1), C(3), C(4), _, C(5)], ListFinal).
```

And now it should give me

```
ListFinal = [C(1), C(3), C(4), C(2), C(5)].
```

How do I do this? How to check for that black space to put there, the constant I haven't used? It is possible to change the implementation of the constants.

Comment: Facts, predicates, and functor names must start with a lower case letter. So constants must be `c(1)`, `c(2)`,....

Comment: okay thanks by the way. Got any ideia how to do that predicate?

Comment: Have you made an attempt you can show?

Comment: What is the criteria you want which would cause `check` to yield `c(3)` in for the anonymous slot, `_`?

Comment: @lurker It's the only fact that hasn't been used. Edit: opps, It's suppose to be c(2)

Comment: Ah... ok that makes more sense. :)

Comment: I've done check(P1, P2):- findall(P1, c(X), P2). And it's not this.

Comment: Are none of the answers given to this problem acceptable?

Answer (score 3):

You could try

```
check( []        , []        ) .
check( [c(X)|Xs] , [c(X)|Rs] ) :- c(X) , check(Xs,Rs) .
```

You might also look at `findall/3`.

You should note however, that your 'constants' aren't constants in prolog. The way you've written them they are are *facts*. And the ones you've listed aren't syntactically valid Prolog: The functor of a term must be either a bareword *atom* like `c(3).` or an atom enclosed in single quotes like `'C'(3).` (though why anybody would voluntarily choose to do something like that is beyond me.)

Comment: I've written with lowercase but I wrote here wrong but yes, they are facts. How findall works?

Comment: @Elsendion : http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse49

Comment: I still don't understand how to write this using the findall/3

Comment: I've using your predicate, and when the check reaches a blank space, he will fill with the first fact declared in the program despite been used or not.

Answer (score 3):

```
check(L, C) :-
    check(L, [], C).
check([], _, []).
check([c(X)|T], A, [c(X)|C]) :-
    c(X),
    \+ memberchk(c(X), A),
    check(T, [c(X)|A], C).
```

Some tests:

```
| ?- check([_, c(3), c(4), _, c(5)], ListFinal).

ListFinal = [c(1),c(3),c(4),c(2),c(5)] ? a

ListFinal = [c(2),c(3),c(4),c(1),c(5)]

no
| ?- check([c(1), c(3), c(4), _, c(5)], ListFinal).

ListFinal = [c(1),c(3),c(4),c(2),c(5)] ? a

no
| ?-
```

Here's a DCG approach:

```
remap([c(X)|T], A) --> {c(X), \+ memberchk(c(X), A)}, [c(X)], remap(T, [c(X)|A]).
remap([], _) --> [].

check(L, C) :- phrase(remap(L, []), C).
```

Answer (score 2):

once corrected the syntax, check each argument (easy to do with maplist/3)

```
check(In, Out) :-
  exclude(var, In, NoVars),
  maplist(check_var(NoVars), In, Out).

check_var(In, X, Y) :-
  var(X) -> c(Z), \+ memberchk(c(Z), In), Y = c(Z) ; Y = X.
```

usage example

```
1 ?- check([c(1),X,c(3),c(5)],L).
L = [c(1), c(2), c(3), c(5)] ;
L = [c(1), c(4), c(3), c(5)] ;
false.
```