# Prolog complete missing elements in list

Tags: list, prolog

Say i have 5 elements that cannot be repeated in a list:
elements are:

```
team(portugal).
team(england).
team(usa).
team(france).
team(spain).
```

and i have the list: [team(france),team(spain),team(portugal),_,team(england)]
as you can see, team(usa) is missing. How can i add it?
i have this predicate availble:

```
put(TEAM,one,[TEAM,_,_,_,_]). %etc, for other positions
```

i tried to:

```
complete(List,CompleteList):-
team(X),member(team(X)),List),put(team(X),_,List).
```

Comment: Your parentheses aren't balanced. Get your code syntactically correct first.

Comment: You might want to look at this [question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23630505/predicate-to-fetch-missing-fact)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your original list has variables, you can just instantiate them without having a "resultant" list:

```
complete(List) :-
    complete(List, []).
complete([], _).
complete([team(X)|T], A) :-
    team(X),
    \+ memberchk(team(X), A),
    complete(T, [team(X)|A]).

| ?- Team = [team(france),team(spain),team(portugal),_,team(england)], complete(Team).

Team = [team(france),team(spain),team(portugal),team(usa),team(england)] ? ;

(1 ms) no
```

It will also work with more than one "blank" in the list.

---

If you want to keep the original list intact, you could do so this way:

```
complete(List, CompleteList) :-
    complete(List, [], CompleteList).

complete([], _, []).
complete([H|T], A, [team(X)|C]) :-
    (   ground(H)
    ->  H = team(X)
    ;   true
    ),
    team(X),
    \+ memberchk(team(X), A),
    complete(T, [team(X)|A], C).
```

This will leave the initial list unground:

```
| ?- Team = [team(france),team(spain),team(portugal),_,team(england)], complete(Team, C).

C = [team(france),team(spain),team(portugal),team(usa),team(england)]
Team = [team(france),team(spain),team(portugal),_,team(england)] ? ;

(1 ms) no
| ?-
```

Comment: This was exactly what i wanted. However, i realy need to have complete/2 one that is incomplete and the other that is complete. Whitout singleton variables. Is it a good idea to copy the List to the CompleteList and then do the complete(CompleteList)?

Comment: @DC17 Out of curiosity, why do you really need to keep the incomplete list? I can't imagine a useful case for this.

Comment: I dont need, the incomplete list, but my predicate has to have 2 args. but i think i can do that. i will simply create a complete/2 where i copy one list to another, and use complete/1 to complete it. Thanks m8.

Comment: @DC17 I added a solution that meets your requirements without doing an explicit list copy.

Comment: @lurker That is great, but i don't need a explicit solution of the incomplete list. I just wanted a complete/2 where complete(List,CompleteList), and the solution displayed were only: CompleteList=[.......]
Besides, i don't understand "ground(H)"

Comment: @DC17 the `ground/1` predicate succeeds if its argument has no variables in it. In the solution I gave, I want to avoid instantiating any unground variables in the initial list, so it checks whether it's ground. The second solution I gave lets you query, `complete(List, CompleteList)` and then `CompleteList` will be the completed list, and `List` will be left alone. I think it does exactly what you want. In the example I gave, I set another variable, `Team` to be the first argument. So the output is showing the value of `Team` as well. It's not another solution.

Comment: @lurker You are great man! Thanks a lot for your help and attention, so as patience.

Answer (score 0):

You might be thinking too much in terms of procedures and not enough in terms of predicates.

It seems you need a predicate `is_complete/1` such that `is_complete(List)` is true if and only if `List` is a list that contains all of your teams, only once. This can be achieved thus:

```
is_complete(List) :-
    setof(X,team(X),Teams),
    length(Teams,N),
    length(List,N),
    foreach(team(X),member(X,List)).
```

You can then backtrack on `is_complete(L)` to have all the possible permutations of your teams. You can check whether a list is complete:

```
is_complete([portugal, england, france, spain, usa]).
```

is true, or use it to complete teams:

```
?- L=[portugal, england, T1, T2, usa], is_complete(L).
L = [portugal, england, france, spain, usa],
T1 = france,
T2 = spain ;
L = [portugal, england, spain, france, usa],
T1 = spain,
T2 = france ;
false.
```

Answer (score 0):

Give you have this fact:

```
Team = [team(france),team(spain),team(portugal),_,team(england)].
```

Then you just have to do this to put `team(usa)` into the list:

```
?- Team = [team(france),team(spain),team(portugal),_,team(england)],
    member(team(usa),Team),
    write(Team).
```

I then get this:

```
[team(france),team(spain),team(portugal),team(usa),team(england)]
```

Comment: That indeed works, however you did not know what team would be missing. Sorry. Probably my fault for not saying that in the beginning.